# javascript function scope challenge

Tags: javascript

I got stuck at a problem in JavaScript which uses the concept of function scope. Particularly, this is what I need to solve:

Define a function named callFunc that takes one argument, a function f. It should return an array containing the values f(0), f(0), f(1), f(1). You can only call f twice.

My code so far is:

```
var f = function(x) {
    return x+2;
};

var callFunc = function (f) {
    return [f(0), f(1)];
};
```

I don't know how I can return an array of four elements using only two calls and the JavaScript function scope principles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really quite simple:

```
function callFunc(f) {
    var f0, f1;
    f0 = f(0);
    f1 = f(1);
    return [f0,f0,f1,f1];
}
```

I'm... not entirely sure why you'd have trouble with that. Reducing the number of function calls is something you should be doing anyway (and it's why I cringe at most jQuery code that has `$(this)` in it like 20 times...)

Comment: Relating to the note about calling `$(this)` 20 times: most front end code should execute asynchronously and perform only minimal work. Because the code generally isn't being executed as part of a UI loop, and instead is being called sporadically these sorts of micro-optimizations are largely unnecessary. In instances where optimization *is* important, reducing function calls is certainly one useful technique, but sometimes writing code clearly is more important than writing code that's as fast as it could possibly be.

Comment: @zzzzBov I mean when you see things like `var t = $(this).text(); $(this).text(t+"123");` (over-simplification). Basically, repeated calls to `$(this)` when you could just do `$this = $(this)` up front and simply reference `$this` thereafter.

Comment: I'm not sure if your code is corect. Here is the link to the problem I'm trying to solve: [Function scope](https://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/lesson?id=1055)

Comment: Oh yes, it was simpler than I thought. Thank you, I just started learning JavaScript yesterday.